# Redirect from controller to another controller

Tags: c#, redirect, controller, redirecttoaction

How can I redirect to another controller correctly?

Im in the RedeAtendimentoController and I want to redirect to my Index action in the Rede_AtendimentoController

['hierarchy' of my controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzhbx.png)

I already try versions of RedirectToAction and RedirectToRoute but isnt working

RedirectToRoute("Rede_Atendimento")
or
RedirectToAction("Index", "Rede_Atendimento");

my controller Rede_AtendimentoController have a [RoutePrefix("Rede_Atendimento")]

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the `area` in the `routeValues` parameter. Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account", new { area = "Admin" });
```

Or

```
return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account", new { area = "" });
```

depending on which area you're aiming for.

Comment: yes already tried this! but I think im not getting the correctly area
I put a image in the question with the folders, if u want to take a look

but this isnt working: return RedirectToAction("Index", "Rede_AtendimentoController", new { area = "Rede_Atendimento" });

Comment: Does it happen to all of your Controllers or only this one ?